# How to find values of bash script variables read-only file?

Tags: debugging, bash, readonly

I have a read-only script in a read-only directory. I only have execute permissions, and can't change it to debug it.
I suppose that the script has an error in its variables definition.
Is it possible to echo the calculated variables without modifying the script, so I can run the final command from the command line?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you copy the script to some different (read-write) folder and debug it there?

Comment: Why can't you make a copy of the script and then edit/run the copy?

Comment: because it uses current directory in variables

Comment: Why can't you make a copy of the script and then edit/run the copy? Folder is read-only

Comment: @user710818 So, in the copy, you can use chdir or cd to go to the right directory from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the [script in debug mode](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) (`bash -x script`) or just copy the file to a writable place, add debugging lines and run it from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the debug mode on.

```
./scriptname -x
```